# erratic behaviour of "\" while storing in DB

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I am saving some texts containing `"\"` in database and `"\"` is getting stored as `&amp;#92;`, `&#92`  and sometimes as `\` itself.

Example:
`"ABC \n\r DEF"` might be stored as

1. `"ABC &#92;n&#92;r DEF"`    or
2. `"ABC &amp;#92;n&amp;#92;r DEF"` or
3. `"ABC \n\r DEF"`

I am not able to find out why data is stored like this in DB. Please help me out in finding out the  root cause for this erratic behaviour. :
(Character Encoding :UTF-8)

The values(with special characters) which i am storing in database are parsed from xml.
Using getNodeValue() i am fetching the value of that node. 
Node is having proper value (ABC \n\r DEF).

While parsing the node , will getNodeValue()  escapes the special characters?

Comment: Something is escaping backslash before it gets to the db at a guess, need some code for each scenario. Can't see it being the db write, unless you are using different encodings or collations at the db end.

Comment: Something, somewhere, is probably calling `UrlEncode` on this text, and something, somewhere else, isn't calling `UrlDecode`. What you end up with in the database depends on how many times the data has followed this broken route. And not at all anything under the database's control.

Comment: If UrlEncode is called , then always the values should have been stored as &#92; instead of "\". This is not happening as the values stored in DB is varying. So i doubt if URLEcode is called or not.